Run elevated process from SYSTEM process
I have a service running as SYSTEM that has to run some applications on users' sessions. I can run non-elevated processes but I can't run elevated processes.
I get the user's token via WTSQueryUserToken (I have user's SessionId), set SeDebugPrivilege, create environment with CreateEnvironmentBlock and then call CreateProcessAsUser. Setting SeDebugPrivilege via AdjustTokenPrivileges fails with ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED error code.
What am I missing? Any help is appreciated. Thanks
bool runPrivilegedProcess(ULONG sessionId)
{
    HANDLE userToken;
    // get user token with sessionId
    if (WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, &userToken) == FALSE)
    {
        debugFile << "WTSQueryUserToken failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (SetPrivilege(userToken, "SeDebugPrivilege") == false)
    {
        debugFile << "SetPrivilege failed\n";
        //CloseHandle(userToken);
        //return false;
    }    

    STARTUPINFOW si;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    memset(&processInfo, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    DWORD dwFlags = DETACHED_PROCESS;

    LPVOID pEnv = NULL;
    if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv, userToken, FALSE))
    {
        dwFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
    }
    else
        debugFile << "CreateEnvironmentBlock failed\n";

    wchar_t processName[100] = L"C:\\windows\\system32\\taskmgr.exe";
    if (CreateProcessAsUserW(userToken, NULL, processName, NULL, NULL, false, dwFlags, pEnv, NULL, &si, &processInfo) == FALSE)
    {
        debugFile << "CreateProcessAsUserA failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(userToken);
        return false;
    }
    debugFile << "Execution done. Child process ID is " << processInfo.dwProcessId << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(userToken);
    return true;
}

bool SetPrivilege(HANDLE hToken, const char* privilegeName)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;
    if(LookupPrivilegeValueA(NULL, privilegeName, &luid) == FALSE)
    {    
        debugFile << "LookupPrivilegeValueA failed: " << privilegeName << " "  << GetLastError() << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid.HighPart = luid.HighPart;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid.LowPart = luid.LowPart;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        debugFile << "AdjustTokenPrivileges error: " << privilegeName << " " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
        return false; // always ends up here
    else
        return true;
}


Of course filtered user token have no debugprivilege, admin group, etc. if user is admin - you can got it linked token and run with it. If user not admin - linked token not exist. You can simply run app with system token in user session.

@RbMm but when I run CreateProcessAsUser with system token, the username of the created process is SYSTEM. I don't want that. I want to have a process with username and elevated privilege; like running via UAC.

Then you have to actually invoke UAC, and you can't do that directly from a service the way you are trying to

You need user SID in token ? You can create such token by self, if user not admin. However - what exactly you need ? What new process need todo ?

I don't want to invoke the UAC. I want to create an elevated process from my service which is SYSTEM and has all the privileges I can think of. I want my process's username be Bob (let's call the user Bob) and the process to be elevated. Just like Bob right clicks on "Run as admin", enter admin credentials and run elevated process in the name of Bob.

so create token for process by self, if you want user SID have specific value. or if user is have elevated linked token - use it

@RbMm I posted the answer. The code runs like UAC: creates an elevated process from SYSTEM user. Although it doesn't work on a user that is not admin. GetTokenInformation returns ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION. Any idea why?

but i say you from begin - if user is admin - you can got it linked token and run with it. - are you read this ? Although it doesn't work on a user that is not admin... Any idea why? of course - because really no such logon session. this solution not work for not admin user

@RbMm Yeah sorry, took me some time to understand. Do you know what is the solution for such cases?

but i already say - for what you need user SID in token ?! what is goal of this process ? if you really need exactly user SID in token user - create token by self. but i dont think this is what you really need.

@RbMm The service runs at Windows Server 2019. Many people login and use it. Under certain conditions my service has to start an elevated GUI process on users' sessions. Some of logged in users are admin and some of them are not admin. If the user is admin, CreateProcessAsUser with linked token runs an elevated process. Great. But if the user is not admin, I don't know what to do. I have local admin's username/password, so I can use LogonUser by the way.

again - run process with your token in user session - in what problem, here ?

@RbMm When I get admin token using WTSQueryUserToken, I can use it on CreateProcessAsUser and create a process, but this method requires that user to be logged in. When I get token from LogonUser, the created process's window is black. The process runs but the GUI is black. Do you know any other way to get a user's token other than LogonUser?

Are you set session id in token ?

@RbMm Yes, using SetTokenInformation(userToken, TokenSessionId, &sessionId, sizeof(DWORD));. I think the way I use LogonUser is wrong. I just found out about an API called ImpersonateLoggedOnUser and RevertToSelf. I think I have to use them somehow. Not sure if I'm in correct way though :(

For what you need impersonate own thread ? If you already have all required privileges. For what need login as another user ?

Scenario: Alice is a limited user and Bob is an admin. I want to create an elevated process in Alice's session. For that, I have to get Bob's token and use CreateProcessAsUser to create an elevated process in Alice's session. If Bob is already logged in, the code that I pasted works. Because I can grab Bob's token using WTSQueryUserToken, get his linked token and create process. But if Bob is not logged in, WTSQueryUserToken will fail obviously. Since my service has Bob's password, I think I have to use LogonUser. But the LogonUser's way creates a black GUI window

This code runs an elevated process from SYSTEM user:
bool runPrivilegedProcess(Process_t* process)
{
    HANDLE userToken, linkedToken;
    ULONG sessionId = process->sessionId;
    if (WTSQueryUserToken(sessionId, &userToken) == FALSE)
    {
        debugFile << "WTSQueryUserToken failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN tokenLinkedToken;
    DWORD tokenSize = sizeof(TOKEN_LINKED_TOKEN), retval;
    if (GetTokenInformation(userToken, TokenLinkedToken, &tokenLinkedToken, tokenSize, &retval) == FALSE)
    {
        debugFile << "GetTokenInformation failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(userToken);
        return false;
    }

    wchar_t desktop[100] = L"winsta0\\default";
    STARTUPINFO si;
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.lpDesktop = desktop;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    wchar_t processName[100] = L"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";
      
    if (!CreateProcessAsUser(tokenLinkedToken.LinkedToken, NULL, processName, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        debugFile << "CreateProcessAsUser error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(userToken);
        CloseHandle(tokenLinkedToken.LinkedToken);
        return true;
    }

    debugFile << "Execution done. Child process ID is " << pi.dwProcessId << std::endl;

    CloseHandle(userToken);
    CloseHandle(tokenLinkedToken.LinkedToken);
    return true;
}

Although it has a flaw: Session 1 is an admin user logged in and it works. Sessoin 2 is a normal user and it doesn't work. The GetTokenInformation returns ERROR_NO_SUCH_LOGON_SESSION (1312).

Think about it. UAC requires an admin user to verify the elevation before the new process can run. You are trying to run the new process as the session user. So, if the session user is not an admin user, it doesn't have the debug privilege present in its token (hence why AdjustTokenPrivileges fails), and can't run elevated processes directly. It needs a separate admin user to approve it.
How do you expect your service to login an admin without their credentials? If you do have their credentials, you can simply use LogonUser() and then use that user's token. But if not, you need to rethink your design.
I would suggest running a separate proxy process un-elevated as the session user, and then have that proxy launch the real target process with ShellExecute/Ex(), using the "runas" verb to invoke a UAC prompt that an admin user can then verify.

Here question what is really need to. If user in admin group - we can got it elevated token. If user not admin - even if we run exe via UAC promt, in token will be SID of some admin, not running user SID. In this case why not system sid ? If exe need access some user registry/folders anyway will be problems, due token refer to another account ( another admin or system). However if we control this exe( write it) it can got user token and impersonate it, for access user specific registry/folders

@Remy I figured out the AdjustTokenPrivileges's problem and my SYSTEM token have any privilege I can think of. The UAC itself is an svchost process running as SYSTEM. So it's possible. I can use LogonUser but will its token run elevated?

@Remy I actually did test LogonUser and it creates elevated process but it doesn't load GUI properly. It's a black window.

Did you see Starting an Interactive Client Process in C++ to start an Interactive Client Process?

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT Thank you Yang. I'll test that.

@YangXiaoPo-MSFT it doesn't run the process elevated unfortunately :(

@MustafaChelik That is because that code is not trying to run it elevated.  It is just merely running it as a logged-in user.
